# How to check if all switch objects in a room are set to true?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I'm trying to implement a puzzle mechanic in Game Maker Studio 2.

Where you need to activate multiple switches for an event to happen (e.g. opening a door)

However, I'm currently stuck in recieving the booleans from *all* switch objects in a room. 
Currently It's only working when *any* (or only the first) switch is hit.

Here's an example of how it works:

Switch collision with projectile:

```
switched = !switched
```

'Switchdoor' step event:

```
if (switch.switched == true) //this only seem te register the first switch placed
{
    //do action
}
```

If I've used XNA, I could make a `List<>` to store all the rendered switches and get their boolean values. But what can I use instead in Game Maker Studio 2, who works with rooms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If my GML is not too rusty, the following should work:

```
var allSwitchesOn = true;

with(switch) {
    if(!switched) {
        other.allSwitchesOn = false;
        break;
    }
}

// allSwitchesOn now has the correct value
```

Comment: Actually this answer should be doing other.allSwitchesOn &= switched or add a break statement when finding that the value is false (though my GML is rusty and unsure if a break would work). I would definitely refactor to just "other.allSwitchesOn &= switched;" within the with statement. The if statement is asking a needless question.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck sorry for the delay. [Documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_13_break.html) says you're right, and short-circuiting the loop is definitely an improvement. Thanks!

Comment: @Quentin that's actually good that you found that because I have about 5 similar with statements that are suffering from efficiency issues. XD